# libcurl on Windows problems

Tags: windows, rubygems, libcurl, curb

I am having a hard time installing libcurl ruby bindings gem (curb) on Windows. I have done everything right. I have libcurl directory on the PATH, and then I try two ways of installing the gem

```
gem install curb
```

and

```
rake install EXTCONF_OPTS='--with-curl-dir=B:\curl'
```

None of them work. They fail with different errors, though, and the second one's error is more constructive:

> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/curb-0.7.7.1/ext/curb_postfield.c:76:
>   undefined reference to
>   'imp_curl_formadd'

But I don't know what this means.

EDIT: The first error is this complaint

> extconf.rb:19:   Can't find libcurl or
>   curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

Even though libcurl dir (B:\curl) is already in the PATH. Here is the full [error message](http://gist.github.com/460344)--I put it ina gist because the formatting was too weird for this place.

Comment: Which Ruby-for-Windows are you using?

If it's the RubyInstaller one ( http://rubyinstaller.org/ )--which you probably should be using, as it is the most stable and cooperative build for Windows right now--then have you installed the DevKit ( http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/development-kit )? (I would assume so, as the error message you listed is referencing the C-code.)

Comment: hey ewell, yes DevKit is installed. The really weird part is installing with gem install complains that it cannot find the libcurl dir. Even though this is already in the PATH. Really confusing situation.

Comment: I edited my question to include the full error messages.

Answer (score 0):

picardo,

I've had trouble installing the curb gem in Windows before. In trying to see how others had solved this I came across a lot of questions and not very many solutions. Having to do it again tonight I decided to document my steps and post the results:
http://beginrescue.blogspot.com/2010/07/installing-curb-with-ruby-191-in.html

Sorry for the blogspam, hope this is useful for somebody.

pete